# Retrieve data From forms.office.com programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, office365, office365api

I've put a public survey form online through https://forms.office.com/ (Office 365)

Is there some way or API I could use to download the results spreadsheet using .NET?

I'm sorry if the question seems silly, but I couldn't find an answer in my research.

Comment: not sure if it helps, but have you checked the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/microsoftforms/

Comment: @sous2817, I'll take alook at it, thank you!

Comment: Do you able to get the solution ?
I also have the exact same situation and want to read the office365 forms programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately an API has been promised for Forms for a long time but has never arrived.

One way is to use a flow in Power Automate to save each form response to a list in SharePoint. You can either see the last week's responses there or you could have another flow with a recurrence schedule trigger set to 1 week. That would get the items created in the list in the last week and do whatever you want to do with it.

or the other way is.
You must first open the URL “https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx” to obtain a token
Then you can call "https://forms.office.com/formapi/DownloadExcelFile.ashx?formid=" + put your form ID Here + "&timezoneOffset=180&minResponseId=1&maxResponseId=1000"

Comment: can you show how to obtain token ?